# How to create button with image and text

Tags: html, css

I'm making a basketball website and I need to make some customized icons/buttons for links to different pages. I want to create a customized button that has a round picture with a picture below.  Below it, I need text.

I don't know how to get the text and the image in the same icon.

Thanks. 
Here's an example of what I want.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xgEo.png

Comment: Have you tried anything? Maybe look at putting an <img> and <p> inside of a <div> with a white background. That should get you started.

Comment: I've tried that but the thing is that the photo always ends up above the actual block of white due to the other rules set on the website

Comment: Then you either need to re-write that CSS to be more specific (IDs and classes) (the right way to solve the problem) or override that CSS by putting CSS closer to the element to correct the element's margins. CSS is applied in the following order: External -> Internal -> In-line. You can also use !important, but this is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try like this:

```css
* {
  boz-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #333;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button figure {
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}

.button figure img {
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.button .text {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #1d368a;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">
  <figure><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100"></figure>
  <div class="text">
    Start Playing Basketball
  </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by using HTML and CSS

```
<div class="container">
<img src="example.jpg" alt="img miss">
<div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>

<style>
.container {
position: relative;
text-align: center;
color: white;
}

.centered {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Can't edit because it's just one character, but **img** is missing a closing tag. ```<img .. />```

Answer (score 1):

Use anchor tag.
For making image and text a link

```
<a href ="link" >
   <div class="class_name" >
      <img src ="image_path" >
      <p> text </p>
   </div>
</a>
```

And for making text as a link

```
<a href ="link" > text </a>
```

When on use anchor tag `<a>` anything like image, text place between `<a>` & `</a>`, will be the link, which onclicking directs us to link mention in `href`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an image to it, or create a link.. 
see an example:

```
<a href=“test.html”>
    <div>
        <img src=“img.jpg” alt=“test”/>
        <p>Link Test</p>
    </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For valid HTML** you have to pay attention to which elements you use. If you use an anchor tag, you can only use inline elements within it. But with CSS you can rephrase everything.

**HTML:**

```
<a class="btn">
    <span class="btn-img"></span>
    <span class="btn-text">Start playing basketball</span>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.btn {  
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:white;
    border-radius:5px;
    position:relative;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}
.btn-img {
    position:relative;
    width:175px;
    height:175px;
    border-radius:50%;
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:red;
    background-image:url(YOUR IMAGE);
 }
 .btn-text {
   text-transform:uppercase;
   font-size:12px;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Had a problem with centering the image but I fixed that with align-items. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the link

https://jsfiddle.net/9wjcya06/

```
<a href ="#" class="btn-link" >
   <div class="button" >
      <img src ="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/40/97/c4/4097c40d4f2e1bbcc9044be03b5f730e.jpg" alt="img" >
      <span> START PLAYING BASKET BALL </span>
   </div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

see code bellow:

```css
.img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    padding: 11px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
.txt{
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
    text-align: center;
    width: 85px;
    color: blue;
    padding-left: 34px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.btn{
    background-color: white;
    
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">
<img class="img" src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg"/>
<p class="txt">strat playing basketball</p>
</button>
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Answer (score 0):

step 1.Add an icon library, such as font awesome.

step 2.append icons to HTML buttons

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font- 
awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
.btn {
background-color: DodgerBlue;
border: none;
color: white;
padding: 12px 16px;
font-size: 16px;
cursor: pointer;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
background-color: RoyalBlue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Icon buttons with text:</p>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</button>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Menu</button>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Trash</button>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-close"></i> Close</button>
<button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Folder</button>

</body>         
</html>
```